# Magento - Associated products are not showing under configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, associate-products

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.9.3.2.

I created configurable product and created an associated products also. My issue is,

1. Configurable products are not displaying front page
2. Associated products also not displaying backend. but if i click on
   reset filter button it is showing simple products which belongs to
   some other configurable products.

[image]

[image]

And i have checked:

1. Stock Availability
2. Qty
3. Website
4. Visibility
5. Catalog
6. Price

All are correct. Does any one know what was the issue?

Comment: check the websites assigned and visibility of configurable product. put catalog,search for configurable product and not visible for associated products

Answer (score 0):

Image 1 show: Your Configurable products haven't Associated products (simple product).
Try to check on 2 check box of image 2 ( product id 33 & 36) and save it.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA-kxb0ZJCI) may be help you understand about magento configurable product